# Cannot reach SSL IP when in docker container over bridge. Getting SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

Tags: docker, ssl, curl, openssl

I'm having issues connecting to any server over IP + TLS but only from within a docker container when running in (the default) network bridge. I am always getting  `OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to W.X.Y.Z`. I've tried tcpdump (in the container) and wireshark (locally on the host) to no avail.

My work partner has the *same OS/Docker version* and cannot reproduce the issue. I'm at a loss as to how to debug this issue.

I have tried:

- various images (ubuntu and alpine)
- various clients (curl and wget)
- various TLS versions (1.3 and 1.2)

**My container:**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y curl tcpdump openssl wget
```

**The issue:**

```sh
docker run -it --rm repro /bin/bash

# in the docker bash shell, if I try to curl a regular https hostname, all is well:
root@ba6f8aab182d:/# curl -v  https://www.google.com
*   Trying 172.217.10.36:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.google.com (172.217.10.36) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  ...


# if I try again but this time with the ip instead of the hostname
root@ba6f8aab182d:/# curl -v https://172.217.10.36
*   Trying 172.217.10.36:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 172.217.10.36 (172.217.10.36) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 172.217.10.36:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 172.217.10.36:443
```

**The above 2 calls (curl HOSTNAME then curl MATCHINGIP) work just fine on the host machine.**

Extra information in the ubuntu container:

```
root@ba6f8aab182d:/# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
root@ba6f8aab182d:/# curl --version
curl 7.68.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.68.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1f zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.7 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.2.0) libssh/0.9.3/openssl/zlib nghttp2/1.40.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2020-01-08
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SPNEGO SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Extra information from the host:

```
$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Cloud integration: 1.0.12
 Version:           20.10.5
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.13.15
 Git commit:        55c4c88
 Built:             Tue Mar  2 20:13:00 2021
 OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.5
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.13.15
  Git commit:       363e9a8
  Built:            Tue Mar  2 20:15:47 2021
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.4.4
  GitCommit:        05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc93
  GitCommit:        12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

```json
$ docker network inspect bridge
[
    {
        "Name": "bridge",
        "Id": "4b8797bccccd628a6280199eb5c0372cd08d521a88a29243b174718569e9cc7e",
        "Created": "2021-04-15T17:24:33.631745871Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ba6f8aab182daebd4f0b0dc449929585637cd46bc532f61991bfa28c40e09ceb": {
                "Name": "flamboyant_zhukovsky",
                "EndpointID": "e29407baf0eb8ac069416a8f787794b548d31f05bf9fb6c223fb58c935aff24c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {
            "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
            "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
            "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
        },
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

**EDIT**

Trying `openssl s_client -cipher ALL -servername 172.217.10.36:443 -connect 172.217.10.36:443` in the container, I get:

```
root@ba6f8aab182d:/# openssl s_client -cipher ALL -servername 172.217.10.36:443 -connect 172.217.10.36:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=0
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 403 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

While on the host I get:

```
openssl s_client -cipher ALL -servername 172.217.10.36:443 -connect 172.217.10.36:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 OU = GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O = GlobalSign, CN = GlobalSign
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Google Trust Services, CN = GTS CA 1O1
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = California, L = Mountain View, O = Google LLC, CN = www.google.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
   i:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
 1 s:/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
   i:/OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2/O=GlobalSign/CN=GlobalSign
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
[... certificate was here ...]
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google LLC/CN=www.google.com
issuer=/C=US/O=Google Trust Services/CN=GTS CA 1O1
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Server Temp Key: ECDH, X25519, 253 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 3206 bytes and written 339 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
    Session-ID: 052A69E409C0705AEAB8A180228C3F8E91A530504EFB06BA9214365F6B99DCAC
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: A4EAC218352BBEAF3A43AB625266304DCF495FFE8A916C638679473AD20DC01B508158B8C0AA39A97003FEC5B8ABD7EC
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 100800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    [... a lot of stuff here ...]
    Start Time: 1618514134
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Comment: What happens when you use then openssl tool:

`openssl s_client -cipher ALL -servername https://172.217.10.36 -connect https://172.217.10.36`

Comment: You might also want to try configuring OpenSSL with “enable-weak-ssl-ciphers” This article sheds more light: https://blog.cloudflare.com/padding-oracles-and-the-decline-of-cbc-mode-ciphersuites/

Comment: I had to modify your command to `openssl s_client -cipher ALL -servername 172.217.10.36:443 -connect 172.217.10.36:443` to get it to do something. I'll amend my post with the answer to this command on both host and container.

Comment: @user4426017+ the only correct value for SNI (-servername) is the DNS name (FQDN), not an IP address, and not port or scheme or anything else; see rfc6066. But OpenSSL doesn't enforce this, and google is big enough they ignore SNI. And anyway it wouldn't differ between host and docker. OP: what do you mean by tcpdump&wireshark 'no avail'? This problem, or at least symptom, is definitely network level. Do you see ClientHello go out, and what if anything happens next, at TCP level? at IP level? at ICMP level? Is it the same outside and inside the container?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 tcpdump on the host shows nothing when attempting to curl from within the container to an IP, but it shows everything correctly when curling with the DNS name (from within the container again). I suspect something is wrong with the docker bridge in this case but I don't know how to debug it.

Answer (score 5):

Seems like the issue is with Docker-For-Mac 3.3.0 and 3.3.1.

The solution was to downgrade to 3.2.2 even though the docker engine is the same.

See https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5568

Comment: Docker 3.3.3 is out and this problem is fixed now. (also related https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5524)

Comment: Confirmed, upgrading from 3.2.2 to 3.2.3 fixes this issue. Mine was also triggered by python requests, error was `(Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, 'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1129)')))`