# Docker Desktop 3.3.0+ breaks SSH on port 443: how to fix?

Tags: docker, ssh, https, http-proxy, docker-desktop

I am using **Docker Desktop for Mac**.

Since version 3.3.0 and with 3.3.1 I cannot connect to altssh.gitlab.com on port 443 any more whereas 3.2.2 and earlier work.

So, these commands both work in 3.2.2 (I downgraded and verified):

```sh
$  ssh git@gitlab.com
$  ssh -p 443 git@altssh.gitlab.com
```

Both produce output like this:

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Welcome to GitLab, @user!
Connection to altssh.gitlab.com closed.
```

With 3.3.0 and 3.3.1 however, only `ssh git@gitlab.com` was working while port 443 was seemingly proxied or intercepted by Docker, resulting in this:

```
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I verified with `nc gitlab.com 22` (netcat) that gitlab.com at port 22 replied:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
```

`nc altssh.gitlab.com 443` also prints that text in 3.2.2 but shows nothing and just hangs in 3.3.0+.

I looked at the release notes for 3.3.0 here:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/

Tried setting `noProxy` in `~/.docker/config.json` because it was mentioned together with HTTPS and restarted Docker Desktop but it changed nothing:

```json
{
 "proxies": {
   "default": {
     "noProxy": "altssh.gitlab.com,075e5c94415c4071840fa96497443943.pacloudflare.com,172.65.251.182,2606:4700:90:0:f0ff:e6a3:2ac:f7ef"
   }
 }
}
```

Is there a way to use Docker 3.3.0+ with SSH on port 443 / altssh.gitlab.com?

Comment: Port 443 is HTTPS, not SSH. I'm not sure why GitLab would ever accept SSH on that port, but you could contact their support department for details.

Comment: @tadman this is a deliberate alternative way to access gitlab.com on port 443 because many enterprise networks block all outbound ports except for HTTP (port 80) / HTTPS (port 443). 443 is usually preferred as its contents is assumed to be unreadable in general so less likely to be modified by enterprise networks. I need to use port 443 because of such settings. It's not just git being used directly but a package manager URL linking to a gitlab.com repository, so if I change the package URL, it breaks deployment. The only alternative would be to not use git repositories to refer to packages.

Comment: This could be an upstream policy change of some kind if you have an IT "department" like that. Maybe it coincidentally came at the same time as the Docker update? It's worth reverting to see if it still works.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've switched to using HTTPS for all container dependencies since it doesn't require bashing around with SSH keys and multi-layer builds.

Comment: Redacted that earlier remark, but some IT departments are so hyper-fixated on the most ridiculous things (like SSH = hackers = bad = let's deep packet inspect and *ban* that) to the point of sabotaging actual work.

Comment: @tadman everyone has reasons for what they're doing :-)  just looking for some easy way around. I can rule out enterprise network because I am accessing gitlab.com from outside enterprise network as well, and it consistently works for Docker Desktop 3.2.2. I want to use SSH instead of HTTPS because of private/public key support instead of username / password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Docker 3.3.2 and newer, the bug has been fixed.

[From the 3.3.2 release notes:](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/)

> •   Disable the HTTP and HTTPS transparent proxies when there is no upstream proxy set. Fixes docker/for-mac#5572.
>
> •   Revert to the HTTP and HTTPS proxy implementation used in 3.2.2.

---

*Previously...*

Looks like the bug is known, though not exactly in this context.

The reason being that supposed "HTTPS" / TLS connections are dropped when they do not use SNI (server name indication), which SSH as a non-SSL/TLS protocol probably does not do.

There's already an open Docker Desktop for Mac issue:
https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/5568

And the linked StackOverflow question:
[Cannot reach SSL IP when in docker container over bridge. Getting SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67114041/cannot-reach-ssl-ip-when-in-docker-container-over-bridge-getting-ssl-error-sysc)